# Alfresco - Get username in workflow

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm searching for the username of `assignees` when I create on a workflow...

I use this:

```
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) {
    // get value of property mymodel:myproperty 
    Object assignees = execution.getVariable("bpm_assignees"); 
}
```

When I get `bpm_assignees` I get this:

> bpm_assignees map value: [Node Type:
>   {alfresco.org/model/content/…}person, Node Aspects:
>   [{alfresco.org/model/content/…}ownable,
>   {alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable,
>   {alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}localized], Node Type:
>   {alfresco.org/model/content/…}person, Node Aspects:
>   [{alfresco.org/model/content/…}ownable,
>   {alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}referenceable,
>   {alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}localized]]

How can I get `username`?

Comment: What's the value type? I'd guess `List<NodeRef>`? Certainly looks to be pointing to people nodes

Comment: I think this is ActivitiScriptNodeList -> http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/ActivitiScriptNodeList.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those objects are the Person NodeRefs. If you fetch back the properties from that node, you'll get things like the user's username, email address etc. You can see what properties are available [by looking at the core content model](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml) (scroll down to cm:person)

Assuming the returned object is an [ActivitiScriptNodeList](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/ActivitiScriptNodeList.html), then they'll come handily wrapped up with accessors etc as they'll be [ActivitiScriptNode](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/ActivitiScriptNode.html)s. Those extend the normal Alfresco JavaScript [ScriptNode objects](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.html). That means that what you'd need to do is:

```
public void notify(DelegateExecution execution){
   ActivitiScriptNodeList assignees = execution.getVariable("bpm_assignees"); 
   for (ActivitiScriptNode personNode : assignees) {
       String username = personNode.getProperties().get("cm:userName");
       String email = personNode.getProperties().get("cm:email");
       // TODO Use this
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's this what I wanted !! :D