# How to get the ID of the process instance in the controller?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-webscripts

My environment:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.d (r134641-b15, Aikau 1.0.101.3, Spring Surf
>   5.2.d, Spring WebScripts 6.13, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r134428-b13) schema 10005

When I start the workflow, I can assign executors - the list of users who will participate in the business process. I need to get a list of all those users and display this list in the reviewTask screen.

To display this data I have the custom FreeMarker template. From this template I'll call my Web Script.

To interact with the repository through REST I use the Web Script Framework MVC - the controller that executes the logic of receiving the list of users and FreeMarker template for the JSON response.

I've been offered [the great idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745913/how-to-queries-all-the-assignments-from-the-repository), how it can be done. But I faced with some problem.

Let's say, I launched multiple instances of the business process. In the Workflow Console I can see the following:

```
id: activiti$1801 , desc: DESCRIPTION_1 , start date: Sun Mar 12 19:19:09 GST 2017 , def: activiti$activitiParallelReview v1
id: activiti$2005 , desc: DESCRIPTION_2 , start date: Sun Mar 12 20:11:57 GST 2017 , def: activiti$activitiParallelReview v1
id: activiti$2138 , desc: DESCRIPTION_3 , start date: Sun Mar 12 20:12:55 GST 2017 , def: activiti$activitiParallelReview v1
```

Thus I have three IDs:

```
activiti$1801
activiti$2005
activiti$2138
```

These IDs are available for me only in the Workflow Console.

How can I get these identifiers in the controller?

Can I, for example, write a class that will be called by Activiti? Let's say,

```
public class SomeListener implements TaskListener {
...
    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
        ...
        String taskId = task.getId();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then attach it to the complete event of the some task and pass ID to the controller.

Is this the right way?..

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

---

I wrote a class that implements the [`ExecutionListener`](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/wf-process-def-listeners-execution.html) interface. Then added it as a listener on the transition from `mswf:submitParallelReviewTask` to `mswf:activitiReviewTask`.

All the properties that I need, I can get here (Thank to [Gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798544/alfresco-get-username-in-workflow)):

```
public class PropertiesReceiver implements ExecutionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(PropertiesReceiver.class);

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String processInstanceId = delegateExecution.getProcessInstanceId();
        logger.debug("processInstanceId == " + processInstanceId);

        ActivitiScriptNodeList assignees = 
                (ActivitiScriptNodeList) delegateExecution.getVariable("bpm_assignees"); 
        for (ActivitiScriptNode personNode : assignees) {
            String username = (String) personNode.getProperties().get("cm:userName");
            logger.debug("username == " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

alfrescotomcat-stdout.2017-03-13.log:

```
...
2017-03-13 11:03:12,244  DEBUG [mswf.bpm.PropertiesReceiver] [http-apr-8080-exec-3] processInstanceId == 26205
2017-03-13 11:03:12,248  DEBUG [mswf.bpm.PropertiesReceiver] [http-apr-8080-exec-3] username == first
2017-03-13 11:03:12,250  DEBUG [mswf.bpm.PropertiesReceiver] [http-apr-8080-exec-3] username == second
...
```

But this is a separate project, packaged in an AMP file.

---

Ok, another way. I can get the id of the process instance in [`ScriptExecutionListener`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/listener/ScriptExecutionListener.html):

```
execution.getProcessInstanceId();
```

And call [the Alfresco REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer) from the Share side to retrieve all the information that I need (Thanks to [Martin Ehe](https://community.alfresco.com/people/mehe)).

For example, this call allows to get all the executors:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/workflow/versions/1/processes/26205/variables
```

,where `26205 == id` of the process instance.

But where should I save this ID to access it from Share? Can I add aspect to the workflow model and whether it's right?..

Comment: Write a [Workflow Delegate in Java](https://summit.alfresco.com/boston/sessions/power-your-activiti-workflow-java-delegates)? That'll get called by Activiti when the workflow has started, or on a transition, to do your custom logic, and it knows what workflow it is

Comment: you can get it by using freemarker template api which gives the current user's task details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this.

```
public JSONObject test(String userName) {


        JSONObject allTasks = new JSONObject();

        companyHome = repository.getCompanyHome();
        try {
            List<WorkflowTask> wft=serviceRegistry.getWorkflowService().getAssignedTasks(userName,WorkflowTaskState.IN_PROGRESS );

                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
                System.out.println("WF sizes = "+wft.size());
                for (WorkflowTask  temp : wft) {
                    JSONObject userWFDetails = new JSONObject();

                    userWFDetails.put("taskId", temp.getId());
                    userWFDetails.put("taskDesc", temp.getDescription());
                    userWFDetails.put("wfInstanceId", temp.getPath().getInstance().getId());

                    System.out.println("wf tasks-"+temp);
                    System.out.println("task id-"+temp.getId());
                    System.out.println("wf instance id-"+temp.getPath().getInstance().getId());
                    System.out.println("wf path id-"+temp.getPath().getId());
                    ja.put(userWFDetails);
                }           
                allTasks.put("userTasksDetails", ja);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allTasks;
    }
```

pass your userName. and you will get all the user task details. workflow instance details in json format.